# I'm trying to create user accounts with a defined password in Ubuntu, problems with crypt?

Tags: python, ubuntu, account

I'm trying to create a script with Python that can create user accounts with pre-defined usernames and passwords from an excel file in Ubuntu. This is my code at the moment:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import crypt
import openpyxl

excel_file = os.open("Names_mod.xlsx", os.O_RDONLY)
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("Names_mod.xlsx")
sheet = wb.active
max_row = sheet.max_row
          
for i in range(1, max_row + 1):
    name = sheet.cell(row = i, column = 5)  
    password = sheet.cell(row = i, column = 6)
    encrypted_password = crypt.crypt(password.value, "22")
    addUser = "sudo useradd -m -p " + encrypted_password + name.value
    os.system(addUser)
```

When I'm running the script through the terminal it runs and gives me no error but no accounts are created. This is from [inside the excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXLhz.png) and as you can see, column E (5) has the usernames and column F (6) has the passwords. I'm aware that os.system is not the best thing to use but I'm doing this as an exercise so there's no security requirements.

Would appreciate some clues and tips :)

Comment: Check errors -- best, switch to [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/subprocess.html) (it's fairly simple to use it) and see what messages you get (I'd expect them on `stderr`).  It's likely saying something at some point but the code isn't looking at it.